# Finding a Strictly Decreasing Partition of 1 with Specific Constraints

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, analysis, number-theory

I'm currently exploring partitions of 1 with specific properties and need some assistance. The problem is as follows:

We need to find a partition of 1, i.e.,
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i = 1,$$
where each $a_i > 0$ is strictly decreasing (that is convergent to $0$). Additionally, for every $i$, there should be no set of non-negative integer coefficients $x_j \in \mathbb{Z}_{>= 0}$

such that the following condition holds:
$$a_i = \sum_{j > i} x_j a_j.$$
In other words, no $a_i$ can be represented as a linear combination, with non-negative integer coefficients, of the subsequent $a_j$'s in the sequence.

I'm seeking a method to construct such a sequence or to understand if such a sequence is even possible under these conditions.

I am able to construct numerous strictly decreasing sequences that partition 1. However, proving their 'linear independence' poses a significant challenge. Are there any known constructions for such sequences where the proof of linear independence is more straightforward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible. Take a running total
$$S_j=\sum_{n=i+1}^{j}x_na_n$$
Then for each $j$, you can just set $x_j$ to the largest possible value without the sum exceeding $a_i$. This guarantees at each step that $a_i-S_j<a_j$, so because $a_j\to0$, $S_j$ must limit to $a_i$.

Comment: What if I relax the requirement such that $a_i = \sum_{j > i} x_j a_j$ cannot be represented as a finite sum, but an infinite sum is permissible?

Comment: Thank you! https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4813824/481713 I've posted another question