# Finding a Strictly Decreasing Partition of 1 with Specific Constraints2

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, analysis, number-theory

Follow-up of the previous question: [Finding a Strictly Decreasing Partition of 1 with Specific Constraints](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4813774/481713)
**We require the sum $a_i \neq \sum_{j>i} x_j a_j$ is a finite sum.**

We need to find a partition of 1, i.e.,
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i = 1,$$
where each $a_i > 0$ is strictly decreasing (that is convergent to $0$). Additionally, for every $i$, there should be no **finite** set of non-negative integer coefficients $x_j \in \mathbb{Z}_{>= 0}$

such that the following condition holds:
$$a_i = \sum_{j > i} x_j a_j.$$
In other words, no $a_i$ can be represented as a **finite linear combination**, with non-negative integer coefficients, of the subsequent $a_j$'s in the sequence.

I'm seeking a method to construct such a sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take $a_n = e^{-n}$, then you get
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i=C$$
Divide all the $a_i$ by $C$ to make them sum to $1$. Then
$$a_i=\sum_{j=i+1}^{k}x_ja_j$$
implies
$$0=-e^{k-i}+\sum_{j=i+1}^{k}x_je^{k-j}$$
Which is a nonzero integer polynomial in $e$. This is a contradiction, as $e$ is transcendental. So this sequence works.

Answer (score 2):

I think the following construction should work. The key idea here is that we shall use the fact that the transcendence degree of $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ is infinite. That is we can find infinitely many positive real numbers call them $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...$ such that there is no algebraic (over $\mathbb{Q}$) relationship between them. Now we shall inductively build our series in the following way we shall pick $a_n$ in the following way, let $a_n=q_n\alpha_n$ where $q_n\in\mathbb{Q}$, and such that $1-\frac{1}{2^n}<\sum_{i=1}^n a_i<1$. You should convince yourself that you can always pick such an $a_n$ (it isn't too hard since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, so you can just scale down $\alpha_n$ to the appropriate size). Now as the $\alpha_i$ have no algebraic relation, your condition of not being an integer linear combination is satisfied. Furthermore, we have that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i=1
$$
Since for any $\epsilon>0$, you can choose $N$ large enough so that $1-\epsilon<1-\frac{1}{2^N}$, so then for $n>N$ we have that  $$1-\epsilon<1-\frac{1}{2^N}<1-\frac{1}{2^n}<\sum_{i=1}^n a_i=1$$
that is by construction the series will converge to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Observations towards a solution. If you're stuck, explain what you tried and why you can't push through.

- If you let $ a_i = \frac{ b_i } { p_i}$ where each $p_i$ is a distinct prime, then you can't express $a_i$ as a finite linear combination with non-negative coefficient, of ANY of the other terms.
- In fact, we could even take $ a_i = \frac{ 1}{ p_i } $ for some suitable subset of primes

  - For an explicit construction, set $ p_i $ to be the smallest prime that is larger than $ \frac{ 1} { 1 - \sum_{j< i } \frac{1}{p_j} } $.